How to get EXPLAIN output with a SELECT statement?
I'm trying to grab a query plan for my query. However, I do not have direct access to the db and can only run SELECT statements on my end.
Is there a way to wrap SELECT around EXPLAIN, maybe even encode it as string to generate tabular data to be extracted on my end.
Note: I cannot use psql (the default command line terminal).

what fot exactly, can't you don't copy it from pgadmin`

And SQL client can send a query to you database, including the EXPLAIN command. You can even ask the database to generate json for you: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html

I can't, no access. Only have access to SELECT in query

I understand that, I went through the documentation, but I do not have access to it and I am only restricted by SELECT statements in a query. Can't download any files either.
I wasn't sure if it is possible without "psql" client

psql is just one of many clients, it's just the default one you get for free when installing PostgreSQL. There are hundreds other SQL clients, you can even use Microsoft Excel to connect to PostgreSQL using ODBC. What client do you use?

I do not use any client. I just have an access to query editor that must have SELECT as the first statement - otherwise error.
It is part of a web application. I'm just looking for ways to extract that query plan using a SELECT query

Ask the one who made your web application. That application has the option to use EXPLAIN, or not.

I'm not aware of any way to sneak an explain in. You can't make it part of a subquery. You could send feedback asking to whitelist explain.

Time to have a talk with your DBA. Contrary to what many developers think they are on the same team and will want to help. But, be prepared to describe why you need this.

So do you have your answer?

Basic EXPLAIN returns a set of text values. But you cannot access that with a plain SELECT. You can EXECUTE EXPLAIN with a given query string dynamically in PL/pgSQL and return  the result as SETOF text. You can even pass EXPLAIN options.
Create the function once. Then you can "call" EXPLAIN via SELECT:
CREATE FUNCTION f_explain(_qry text, _options text = NULL)
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
  format('EXPLAIN %s %s', _options, _qry);
END
$func$;

Example calls:
SELECT * FROM f_explain('SELECT 1');
SELECT * FROM f_explain('SELECT 1', '(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)');

Options, if given, must be in legal syntax form.
fiddle
Careful! With the option ANALYZE, the given query string is actually executed. Also, a maliciously formed query string can do anything the executing role is allowed to do. So this is open to SQL injection. Handle with care!
Related:

EXPLAIN ANALYZE within PL/pgSQL gives error: "query has no destination for result data"

Alternatively, you can get EXPLAIN output string of messages (NOTICE, WARNING, ...) See:

Getting the query plan for statements inside a stored procedure in PostgreSQL

